# Automatically importing UnityEngine in generated MessagePack resolvers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, msgpack

I'm trying to start using `MessagePack` in my Unity project. I've followed [the instructions](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) to generate resolvers using `mpc` through the provided Unity editor plugin, since my project needs to be AOT.

It works, but if my classes contain members of Unity types e.g. `Vector3`, the generated code doesn't recognize them unless I manually import `UnityEngine` in the generated file.

That's fine, but it makes me wonder if I'm missing something or rather, is there a way to tell the generator to add certain imports automatically?